# Get All Properties that was Overridden base on Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I have get all the property by reflection using `System.Reflection.PropertyInfo`

Question: how can I verify if property is overridden?

(a bool can do ...)

Comment: please show what you've currently tried

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect if a method was overridden using Reflection (C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932421/detect-if-a-method-was-overridden-using-reflection-c)

Comment: Another duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505232/how-do-i-determine-if-a-property-was-overriden

Comment: @DavidL, Question1 1 requires "class" to get type and that was for method, im looking for "property"...
Question2 wanted all: Public properties, that are "not" overridden